# Android application orientation change behavior

Tags: android, testing, screen-orientation

I'm done with developing an android application and in phase of testing it. I've tested it with the simulator and everything is working perfect, but when I deploy it on devices, some of them when you change the screen orientation the application screen starts to flicker.

Any clue where to start the problem investigation from?

Comment: Are you getting any error message? You can fix screen orientation for all screens

Comment: do you have different layouts for port and land?

Comment: What do you mean by "starts to flicker". Does it flicker once, does it keep on flickering? At what speed does it flicker? Is it going " "black <> white" or "app <> black" or "app <> white", is your app still working during the flicker (if that is more then once), or does it still work after the flickering stops (if it ever stops).

Comment: 1- No error message - in response to Krishna.

Comment: 2- Only one layout with tabhost host. - in response to Theoosh

Comment: 3- the behavior is "app <> black" and the application is hanged where you can't do anything. the flickering is there as long as the app is running and it stops when you force quit the app. - in response to Nanne

Answer (score 1):

When orientation changes from portrait to landscape or vice versa, onCreate gets called again, making the application to start from the beginning. Make sure you are handling it in manifest by declaring `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` infront of your class name or override `onConfigChanged()` function.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this was solved, I discovered that I'm implementing the onOrientationChange method two times that's way the behavior was there. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Both Device version and Developing Application Versions are the same or not, and clear the application after install to the device and then run.